# How verify where some statement is added to the EntityManager JPA

Tags: java, jpa, entitymanager

Good morning in my timezone,

When i call a query through EntityManager to do a select, it throws me an Exception saying that an insert statement can not have NULL values.My question is:
How can i find where this insert is hapenning ?

Best regards
Thanks in advance

Comment: could you share a stack trace?

Comment: What JPA Provider are you using?

Comment: provider that comes with WebSphere

Comment: which is ? Hibernate? OpenJPA? EclipseLink? DataNucleus?

Comment: "Websfear JPA 1.0" isn't a JPA provider, its a level of JPA. Just post the stack trace of this exception you mention ("e.printStackTrace") and add it to your question. Ought to be obvious from that

Answer (score 0):

Usually ORMs flush the current session state before selecting new values from the database. to find the origin of your offending insert, you could flush the session deliberately after object manipulations.